# Technical inside : why does this iteration not find my item

Tags: c#, lambda

Hey people 
yesterday i was working on some code and thought that i would save a foreach iteration and use the find extension on the List<> object, but i never got it to work. later i refactored the the code to use a foreach with a lamda where statement and that found my item evrytime.

my 2 versions of code are posted below:

Not working version:

```
private XmlCell FindCell(string id)
    {
        XmlSection section = new XmlSection(SectionNode);
        XmlCell currentCell = null;

        foreach (XmlBlock block in section.Blocks)
        {
            foreach (XmlRow row in block.Rows)
            {
                currentCell = row.Cells.Find(cell => string.Equals(cell.Id, id));
            }
        }

        Assert.IsNotNull(currentCell, string.Format("Cell with id {0} not found", id));
        return currentCell;
    }
```

working version :

```
XmlSection section = new XmlSection(SectionNode);
XmlCell currentCell = null;

foreach (XmlBlock block in section.Blocks)
{
    foreach (XmlRow row in block.Rows)
    {
        foreach (XmlCell cell in row.Cells.Where(cell => string.Equals(cell.Id, id)))
        {
            return cell;
        }
    }
}

Assert.IsNotNull(currentCell, string.Format("Cell with id {0} not found", id));
return currentCell;
```

could someone plx explain why the first bit of code dont get the job done, msdn says that the find method returns the first instance it finds in the list.

i even encountered some "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute" errors, why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the next iteration will make your variable `currentCell` null again when `Find` didn't find the cell with the matching ID. In the second piece of code you return the found cell immediately.

In the first piece of code try this:

```
foreach (XmlRow row in block.Rows)
{
 currentCell = row.Cells.Find(cell => string.Equals(cell.Id, id));
 //new
 if (currentCell != null)
  return currentCell;
 //end new
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you find your cell with the specified ID, the `currentCell` is set to this specific object. However, on the next iteration in the foreach loop, `currentCell` is set to nothing, because `Find` returns nothing :)

```
 foreach (XmlRow row in block.Rows)
  {
     currentCell = row.Cells.Find(cell => string.Equals(cell.Id, id));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2 versions of code are different - second one returns from all nested loops as soon as it finds a matching cell, while first one returns presence of the cell in the last row of the last block.

Fix - add check for finding the cell in inner loop and retrun as soon one found:

```
foreach (XmlBlock block in section.Blocks)        
{  
    foreach (XmlRow row in block.Rows)             
    {                 
         currentCell = row.Cells.FirstOrDefault(cell => string.Equals(cell.Id, id));             
         if (currentCell != null) 
           return currentCell;

    }
}
```